# I am trying to make a weekly projection using nested if in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have this statement in Excel (Nested IF)

```
 =IF(E3-B3>0,E3-B3,IF(D3-B3>0,(D3-B3),IF(C3-B3>0,C3-B3," ")))
```

What I am missing is that he 250 value on the last Cell H3 (Dollars to Budget MTD) have to be calculated only (E3-B3)30-50 and returning  -20 as a result. However, it is returning 250 which is wrong in my logic.

[The 250 value on the last Cell H3 (Dollars to Budget MTD
) have to be calculated only 30 -50 = -20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pJu9.png)

[image]

Comment: Look at the logic, `If E3-B3>0` then return `E3-B3`.  In your example, `E3-B3` is less than 0 (it's `-20`), so it's going to `If D3-B3>0`, which is `TRUE`.... Perhaps you want `If(ABS(E3-B3)>0,...`?

Comment: No it is **right** in your logic. E3-B3 is a negative value so that is **not** greater than zero and is discarded. Then D3-B3 **is** greater then zero and that result (e.g. 250) is returned to the cell. C3-B3 is not calculated because D3-B3 was processed.

Comment: You need  `=IF(E3-B3<0,E3-B3,IF(D3-B3<0,(D3-B3),IF(C3-B3<0,C3-B3," ")))` but what if more than one week is over action plan? do you want the sum of the difference?

Comment: I want all the logic to remain the same. I know my nested if will extend when more weeks projection will be added. Is there a better way to perform that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

I simply used a dummy value A in your formula which will never be true

```
=IF(E3-B3<>"A",E3-B3,IF(D3-B3<>"A",(D3-B3),IF(C3-B3<>"A",C3-B3," ")))
```

Comment: I see that did it disregarding the other if functions meaning if I add a value in the next cell the result will remain the same.

Comment: then we would need to include more if conditions which would include other cells too

Comment: Are those if conditions we will add will be extension and nested if ?

Comment: Yes. something like this =IF(E3-B3<>"A",E3-B3,IF(D3-B3<>"A",(D3-B3),IF(F3-B3<>"A",(F3-B3),IF(C3-B3<>"A",C3-B3," ")))

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the last number in C3:G3 as the minuend, B3 as the subtrahend and the difference in H3. Try this in H3,

```
=index(B3:G3, match(1e99, B3:G3))-B3
'... for a running total then,
=sum(C3:G3)-B3
```

As soon as you fill in F3, either of the formulas will adjust.

Comment: Well, I am really new to Excel Formulas, if you can explain more, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Assuming that you have gone to support.office.com and looked at the documentation  for both INDEX and MATCH (and you shouldn't be asking if you haven't), then what part of it do you not understand? Are either of the formulas doing what you want to happen?

Comment: I will have to read on that hopefully I will have the time. But is that the best way to achieve my logic and better than if statement?